# C++ Makefile with source in multiple directories and multiple executables

Tags: c++, makefile, project-structure

I have a small project for school and I want to write a decent Makefile, I have seen some examples of using Makefile with multiple source directories and multiple executables but still could not implement it properly to my Makefile.

Here is the directory structure:

```
.
├── bin (this is where i want the executables)
├── build (this is where i want the .o)
├── extern
│   └── doctest.h
├── include
│   ├── file1.hpp
│   └── file2.hpp
├── src
│   ├── file1.cpp
│   └── file2.cpp
├── tests
│   ├── file1-test.cpp
│   └── file2-test.cpp
└──  Makefile
```

PS: I'm using doctest for the unit testing (and i can't change).

Here is my Makefile for the moment:

```
BIN_DIR = ./bin/
BUILD_DIR = ./build/
EXTERN_DIR = ./extern/
INCLUDE_DIR = ./include/
SOURCE_DIR = ./src/
TESTS_DIR = ./tests/

CXX = clang++-7
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 -g -O3 -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)

EXEC_FILES = file1 file2
BIN = $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR), $(EXEC_FILES))

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN_DIR) $(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)%.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o: $(TESTS_DIR)%.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(EXTERN_DIR) -c -o $@ $^

$(BIN_DIR)file1-test: $(BUILD_DIR)file1.o $(BUILD_DIR)file1-test.o | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

$(BIN_DIR)file2-test: $(BUILD_DIR)file1.o $(BUILD_DIR)file2.o $(BUILD_DIR)file2-test.o | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN_DIR)* $(BUILD_DIR)*
```

It's working well but I feel like it's doing useless stuff that i could avoid with more knownledge in the Makefile art, sadly I don't have much time.

My goal:

- I want to run `make` and compile all the units tests (all the `.cpp` in the `tests/` directory) and the main program (see PS below).
- I want all the executables in the `bin/` directory and all the binary files in the `build/` directory.

PS: I don't have my main executable yet but it should be stored in the `src/` directory at the very end (and be compiled as well while running `make`).

**EDIT 1:**

Basically, my question is: How can I write generic rules to prevent copying this (see below) for every new executable in my project ?

```
$(BIN_DIR)file2-test: $(BUILD_DIR)file1.o $(BUILD_DIR)file2.o $(BUILD_DIR)file2 test.o | $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^
```

**EDIT 2:**

After some changes, I ended up with this:

```
BIN_DIR = ./bin/
BUILD_DIR = ./build/
EXTERN_DIR = ./extern/
INCLUDE_DIR = ./include/
SOURCE_DIR = ./src/
TESTS_DIR = ./tests/

vpath %.cpp $(SOURCE_DIR) $(TESTS_DIR)

CXX = clang++-7
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 -g -O3 -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -I$(EXTERN_DIR)

EXEC_FILES = file1-test file2-test
BIN = $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR), $(EXEC_FILES))

all: $(BIN) | $(BIN_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o: %.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

# The problem is here
$(BIN_DIR)%: $(BUILD_DIR)%.o
    @$(CXX) -o $@ $^

$(BIN_DIR) $(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    -@rm -f $(BIN_DIR)* $(BUILD_DIR)*
```

I understand this rule (see below) like this: Compile every target in `EXEC_FILES` to the `bin/` directory, from **his equivalent `.o` (obj) in the `build/` directory**.

```
$(BIN_DIR)%: $(BUILD_DIR)%.o
    @$(CXX) -o $@ $^
```

But in fact I need a rule that will: Compile every target in `EXEC_FILES` to the `bin/` directory, from **all their related `.o` (obj) in the `build/` directory**.

Comment: Good start. Idea: keep only generic recipes:
(`$(BIN_DIR)/%:$(OBJ_DIR_APP)/%.o $(OBJ_DIR_LIB)/*`). This implies a clear separation of obj folders holding "library" code and those holding programs.

Comment: But your question is unclear, you should focus on some clear question to get an answer.

Comment: When making changes in my file and directory 'layout', I find it helpful to have a makefile in every 'code' directory (dirs with .cpp files, currently 4 dirs).  The single do-all makefile would invoke them, and would not have to change as you add functionality or split over large .cpp files.

Comment: @kebs I tried to edit my original post but it seems that you already answered the question.

Comment: @2785528 I'll try this approach if I can't find anything satysfying with mine, thanks anyway.

Comment: @kebs I edited it once again with the new stuff I found.

Comment: @Nelson, it doesn't work that way. As I said above, it is unclear what you want. I suggest you open a new question, with a clear problem that can be answered. Please read some of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking . As such, your question is not answerable and will eventually be closed.

Comment: @kebs My question is quite simple: Is it possible to write some generic rules that fetch all the .o needed for an executable and link them together without having to write it for every new executable, and if so, where should I look for more documentation or help ? I assume that this is exactly what I'm asking in my post.

Comment: @kebs looking at some posts I thought it was about "Autodependencies" but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: In my opinion, the first step in producing a "decent" makefile would be to abandon the idea of building object files and binaries to their own, special directories.  Makefiles that do that are one of my pet peeves.  You have to do extra work and make your Makefile more complicated to achieve it, all for an outcome that is of little practical value.  Write a good `clean` target instead, and / or plan to use VPATH for out-of-source building.

Comment: How is Make to know which object files are needed for an executable? Are you willing to provide a list? Does a directory contain all of the corresponding source files (and no others)?

Comment: "My question is quite simple" Then edit your question to make that clear! It is not at present. And the short answer is "yes", of course.